# Access value of PHP $ahTime[$day]['allDay'] in Smart 2.0 template?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have a PHP value `$ahTime[$day]['allDay']` and I want to access that value in Smarty. What is the syntax?  Smarty `{$day}` is already updated in a Smarty `{foreach}` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax can be found in the documentation of the Smarty library (I hope this syntax is valid for the version of Smarty you're using):

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl#id450263

```
{assign var=result value=$ahTime[$day].allDay}
```